# Are the following statements equivalent in C?

Tags: c, if-statement

If my_function() returns a 0 for success or -EINVAL for failure, then would these two statements be equivalent?

```
if( my_function() ){
```

and

```
if( my_function() == 0){
```

I'm aware that 1 is boolean True and 0 is boolean False in C, so I wasn't sure if the first statement would fail the if statement if my_function() successfully returned 0.

Comment: Um... "Equivalent"? They are actually *opposite* to each other. The first version checks for failure, while the second one checks for success.  `if( my_function() != 0){` would be the exact equivalent of the first version.

Comment: That answers my question; if you'd like to make that an answer I'll accept it then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C in boolean context expression `a` is typically equivalent to expression `a != 0`. This means that your first variant

```
if( my_function() ){
```

is equivalent to

```
if( my_function() != 0 ){
```

This in turn means that your second variant is not equivalent to the first one. It is actually *opposite* to the first one. Your first version checks for failure, while the second one checks for success.

Answer (score 2):

According to the C Standard (6.8.4.1 The if statement)

> 2 In both forms, the first substatement is executed **if the
>   expression compares unequal to 0**....

And (6.5.9 Equality operators)

> 3 The == (equal to) and != (not equal to) operators are analogous to
>   the relational operators except for their lower precedence.108) **Each
>   of the operators yields 1 if the specified relation is true** and 0 if
>   it is false....

So the expression in this if statement

```
if( my_function() ){
```

compares unequal to 0 if the function returns a non-zero value.

In this if statement

```
if( my_function() == 0){
```

the expression `my_function() == 0` compares unequal to 0 if the function returns 0 because in this case the relation is true and yields 1.

So these if statements are opposite each other.

Equivalent if statements would be

```
if( !my_function() ){
```

or if to include the header `<iso646.h>`

```
if( not my_function() ){
```

and

```
if( my_function() == 0){
```